# How to specify log file name with spider's name in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy,in my scrapy project,I created several spider classes,as the official document said,I used this way to specify log file name:

```
 def logging_to_file(file_name):
"""
@rtype: logging
@type file_name:str
@param file_name:
@return:
"""
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=filename+'.txt',
    filemode='a',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.DEBUG,

)
 Class Spider_One(scrapy.Spider):
      name='xxx1'
      logging_to_file(name)
  ......
 Class Spider_Two(scrapy.Spider):
      name='xxx2'
      logging_to_file(name)
  ......
```

Now,if I start `Spider_One`,everything is correct!But,if I start `Spider Two`,the log file of `Spider Two` will also be named with the name of `Spider One`!
I have searched many answers from google and stackoverflow,but unfortunately,none worked!
I am using python 2.7 & scrapy 1.1!
Hope anyone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you initiate `logging_to_file` every time when you load up your package. You are using a class variable here where you should use instance variable.

When python loads in your package or module ir loads every class and so on.

```
class MyClass:
    # everything you do here is loaded everytime when package is loaded
    name = 'something'

    def __init__(self):
        # everything you do here is loaded ONLY when the object is created
        # using this class
```

To resolve your issue just move `logging_to_file` function call to your spiders `__init__()` method.

```
class MyClass(Spider):
    name = 'xx1'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        logging_to_file(self.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I have tried moving `logging_to_file` function to each spider's `__init__` method yesterday,but If I did so,log file won't be created.

Comment: @nick how are you running your spider? There's no way `logging_to_file` of other spiders should be reached if you are running with `scrapy crawl spider_name`

Comment: yes,I really used `scrapy crawl spider_name` command to run my spider!!@Granitosaurus

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define the [`LOG_FILE`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-file) setting in [`Spider.custom_settings`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings):

```py
from scrapy import Spider


class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["https://toscrape.com"]

    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": f"{name}.log",
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

However, because logging starts before the spider custom settings are read, the first few lines of the log will still go into the [standard error output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)).